# HTTP to HTTPS redirect not working on Apache with PHP

Tags: php, apache, http, redirect, https

I have a script that handles several different redirects on a server with a snippet that looks like follows:

```
if($url == "http://www.url.com")
    {header("Location: https://www.url.com/index.html");}
```

The script works exactly as intended with one issue - all of the https redirects end up redirecting to http (versus the https as defined).

Does anyone have any ideas what may be going on?

Comment: Impossible to see without further knowledge about the webserver setup, but as it stands (and you get $url from somewhere), it should work. So there are other mechanisms at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was something else going on with the server, but it's been a while so I can't remember what it was anymore.

Comment: So you can confirm the problem was in the http-server setup?

Comment: Seriously, just kill the question if there is no meaningful answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The server you redirect to has a redirect of its own to http.

Nothing you can do about it, unless you are administering that server.

Comment: Is there a way or something I should be looking for to verify that?

Comment: Use something like HTTPFox (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647/) to view the headers/bodies of all requests performed by the browser. If the HTTPS pages are doing their own redirect, you'll be able to winkle out how/when from that.